# Update balances in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sql-update

I have an `Operation` table that contains 5 columns:

- id
- bankAccount_id
- valueDate
- debit (always positive)
- credit
- balance

I want to update the balance of all the operations of a bank account.

I ended up with this SQL request after reading some SO questions & answers:

```sql
UPDATE Operation INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    id,
    credit,
    debit,
    @Balance := @Balance + IFNULL(credit,0) - IFNULL(debit,0) AS Balance
  FROM Operation, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit
  WHERE bankAccount_id = 1
  ORDER BY valueDate ASC, id ASC
) subRequest ON Operation.id = subRequest.id 
SET Operation.balance = subRequest.Balance;
```

It works well when the operations' valueDates are in the same order than IDs. But when there are operations with big IDs first, it does not work.

As you can see the operation 22 is the last one updated, despite it is the first one ordered by value date!

```
+----+---------------------+--------+---------+---------+
| id | valueDate           | debit  | credit  | balance |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 22 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |   NULL |  103.00 |  618.00 |
|  1 | 2020-01-15 14:00:00 |   NULL | 1000.00 | 1000.00 |
|  2 | 2020-01-15 15:00:00 |   NULL |  200.00 | 1200.00 |
|  3 | 2020-01-15 16:00:00 |  50.00 |    NULL | 1150.00 |
|  4 | 2020-01-18 17:00:00 | 200.00 |    NULL |  950.00 |
|  5 | 2020-01-19 18:00:00 |   NULL |   20.00 |  970.00 |
|  6 | 2020-01-21 20:00:00 | 500.00 |    NULL |  470.00 |
|  7 | 2020-01-21 20:00:00 |  10.00 |    NULL |  460.00 |
|  8 | 2020-01-21 20:00:00 |   NULL |   30.00 |  490.00 |
|  9 | 2020-02-02 01:00:00 |   5.00 |    NULL |  485.00 |
| 10 | 2020-02-10 09:00:00 |  10.00 |    NULL |  475.00 |
| 11 | 2020-02-11 10:00:00 |   NULL |   40.00 |  515.00 |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------+---------+
```

What I do not understand is that when I run the inner query alone, it returns the operations with the right order **and the right balance**!

What can I do to make my update query working?

Here is the data structure you can use for testing:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Operation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `valueDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `debit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `bankAccount_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Operation` VALUES (1,'2020-01-15 13:00:00',NULL,1000.00,0.00,1),(2,'2020-01-15 14:00:00',NULL,200.00,0.00,1),(3,'2020-01-15 15:00:00',50.00,NULL,0.00,1),(4,'2020-01-18 16:00:00',200.00,NULL,0.00,1),(5,'2020-01-19 17:00:00',NULL,20.00,0.00,1),(6,'2020-01-21 19:00:00',500.00,NULL,0.00,1),(7,'2020-01-21 19:00:00',10.00,NULL,0.00,1),(8,'2020-01-21 19:00:00',NULL,30.00,0.00,1),(9,'2020-02-02 00:00:00',5.00,NULL,0.00,1),(10,'2020-02-10 08:00:00',10.00,NULL,0.00,1),(11,'2020-02-11 09:00:00',NULL,40.00,0.00,1),(12,'2020-01-21 19:00:00',NULL,500.00,0.00,2),(13,'2020-01-22 20:00:00',NULL,15.00,0.00,2),(14,'2020-02-02 00:00:00',NULL,5.00,0.00,2),(15,'2020-02-05 03:00:00',30.00,NULL,0.00,2),(16,'2020-02-10 08:00:00',NULL,60.00,0.00,2),(17,'2019-12-30 22:00:00',NULL,50.00,0.00,3),(18,'2020-01-21 19:00:00',10.00,NULL,0.00,3),(19,'2020-01-21 19:00:00',30.00,NULL,0.00,3),(20,'2020-01-21 19:00:00',100.00,NULL,0.00,3),(21,'2020-01-27 22:00:00',NULL,55.00,0.00,3),(22,'2017-12-31 23:00:00',NULL,103.00,0.00,1);
```

And you can order operations with:

```sql
select * from Operation where bankAccount_id = 1 ORDER BY valueDate ASC, id ASC;
```

Comment: Can you also show us the expected output?

Comment: I think you showed us output. Can you show some sample input? And, what version of MySQL do you use?  Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables and ordering together are tricky. Does it work better if you order in a subquery first, and then compute the variable?

```
UPDATE operation o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        o1.id, 
        @balance := @balance + IFNULL(o1.credit, 0) - IFNULL(o1.debit, 0) AS balance
    FROM (
        SELECT id, credit, debit 
        FROM Operation 
        WHERE bankAccount_id = 1 
        ORDER BY  valueDate ASC, id ASC
    ) o1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS v
) s ON o.id = s.id 
SET o.balance = s.balance;
```

Note that if you are running MySQL 8.0, this is much simpler done with window functions:

```
UPDATE operation o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        SUM(IFNULL(o1.credit, 0) - IFNULL(o1.debit, 0)) 
            OVER(ORDER BY valueDate, id) balance
    FROM Operation 
    WHERE bankAccount_id = 1
) s ON o.id = s.id 
SET o.balance = s.balance;
```

Comment: Thanks it is working with version 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. And thanks for the MySQL 8.0's tip!